# Discord.py Bot issue with youtube-dl

Tags: discord, discord.py, youtube-dl

I'm having a strange issue with my discord bot. Up until today all was fine but all of a sudden when I use my >play command with a search query like >play spiderman pizza for example I get 'WARNING:root:NoneType: None' right when the video is about to play. If I use a URL after the >play command, it still works flawlessly as it did before. I've looked and I just cant see the issue. This is the main code of my play command with stuff like the queuing system and permission checking taken out as it's not related.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx,*, url):
                server = ctx.message.server
                voice_client = client.voice_client_in(server)
                player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url, ytdl_options={'default_search': 'auto'}, after =lambda: check_queue(server.id))
                players[server.id] = player
                player.volume = 0.18
                embed=discord.Embed(title=("⏬ Audio downloaded succesfully ⏬"), color=0x9400D3)
                await client.say(embed=embed)
                await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
                embed=discord.Embed(title=(player.uploader), description=(player.description), color=0x9400D3)
                embed.set_author(name=(player.title), url=(player.url) , icon_url='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/YouTube_Music.png')
                embed.add_field(name="Duration(in seconds):", value=(player.duration), inline=True)
                embed.add_field(name="Current Views:", value=(player.views), inline=True)
                embed.add_field(name="Likes:", value=(player.likes), inline=True)
                embed.add_field(name="Dislikes:", value=(player.dislikes), inline=True)
                embed.set_footer(text=random.choice(messages))
                await client.say(embed=embed)
                players[server.id] = player
                player.start()
                await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
                embed=discord.Embed(title=(" Now Playing "), color=0x9400D3)
                await client.say(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Why do you assume the ytdl player "knows" about searching?  What do you expect it to do?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Because it has worked in the past and is a function of it. However since yesterday it'll download the video and then throw out a warning when it goes to play it.

Comment: Could you share the full error message?  If you include the minimum code needed to play a video, does the problem remain?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Sorry about the late reply, was at work. This is what I get in the Visual Studio Code terminal.                                                        
`[youtube:search] query "vsauce": Downloading page 1
[download] Downloading playlist: vsauce
[youtube:search] playlist vsauce: Collected 1 video ids (downloading 1 of them)
[download] Downloading video 1 of 1
[youtube] O2jkV4BsN6U: Downloading webpage
[youtube] O2jkV4BsN6U: Downloading video info webpage
[download] Finished downloading playlist: vsauce
WARNING:root:NoneType: None`